# How to extract all instances of specifics groups in this complicated regex for PGN games?

Tags: regex, scala

I am trying to parse a chess PGN file, but don't manage to fetch all instances of the several moves and tags.

I've taken [this regex](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=3355), and added two capturing groups name : tag and move, which leads me to the following one :

```
private val pgnRegex = """(?<pgnGame>\s*(?<tag>\[\s*(?<tagName>\w+)\s*"(?<tagValue>[^"]*)"\s*\]\s*)*(?<move>(?<moveNumber>\d+)(?<moveMarker>\.|\.{3})\s*(?<moveValue>(?:[PNBRQK]?[a-h]?[1-8]?x?(?:[a-h][1-8]|[NBRQK])(?:\=[PNBRQK])?|O(-?O){1,2})[\+#]?(\s*[\!\?]+)?)(?:\s*(?<moveValue2>(?:[PNBRQK]?[a-h]?[1-8]?x?(?:[a-h][1-8]|[NBRQK])(?:\=[PNBRQK])?|O(-?O){1,2})[\+#]?(\s*[\!\?]+)?))?\s*(?:\(\s*(?<variation>(?:(?<varMoveNumber>\d+)(?<varMoveMarker>\.|\.{3})\s*(?<varMoveValue>(?:[PNBRQK]?[a-h]?[1-8]?x?(?:[a-h][1-8]|[NBRQK])(?:\=[PNBRQK])?|O(-?O){1,2})[\+#]?(\s*[\!\?]+)?)(?:\s*(?<varMoveValue2>(?:[PNBRQK]?[a-h]?[1-8]?x?(?:[a-h][1-8]|[NBRQK])(?:\=[PNBRQK])?|O(-?O){1,2})[\+#]?(\s*[\!\?]+)?))?\s*(?:\((?<varVariation>.*)\)\s*)?(?:\{(?<varComment>[^\}]*?)\}\s*)?)*)\s*\)\s*)*(?:\{(?<comment>[^\}]*?)\}\s*)?)*(?<endMarker>1\-?0|0\-?1|1/2\-?1/2|\*)?\s*)""".r
```

I've tried to parse the Pgn with the following object :

```
package com.loloof64.scala.pgn_to_pictures.pgn_parsing

import java.io.File
import scala.io.Source

object PgnReader {

def parseFile(inputFile:File) = {
    val pgnStream = Source.fromFile(inputFile)
    val pgnStr = pgnStream.mkString
    pgnRegex.findAllIn(pgnStr).matchData.foreach{
      currMatchData => if (!currMatchData.toString.isEmpty) {
        currMatchData.subgroups.foreach { currGroup => println(s"Group id => ${currGroup}") }
      }
    }
    pgnStream.close
  }

  /* thanks to Siderite : http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=3355 
   * Adapted by Laurent Bernabe : added some capturing groups (tag and move) */
  private val pgnRegex = """(?<pgnGame>\s*(?<tag>\[\s*(?<tagName>\w+)\s*"(?<tagValue>[^"]*)"\s*\]\s*)*(?<move>(?<moveNumber>\d+)(?<moveMarker>\.|\.{3})\s*(?<moveValue>(?:[PNBRQK]?[a-h]?[1-8]?x?(?:[a-h][1-8]|[NBRQK])(?:\=[PNBRQK])?|O(-?O){1,2})[\+#]?(\s*[\!\?]+)?)(?:\s*(?<moveValue2>(?:[PNBRQK]?[a-h]?[1-8]?x?(?:[a-h][1-8]|[NBRQK])(?:\=[PNBRQK])?|O(-?O){1,2})[\+#]?(\s*[\!\?]+)?))?\s*(?:\(\s*(?<variation>(?:(?<varMoveNumber>\d+)(?<varMoveMarker>\.|\.{3})\s*(?<varMoveValue>(?:[PNBRQK]?[a-h]?[1-8]?x?(?:[a-h][1-8]|[NBRQK])(?:\=[PNBRQK])?|O(-?O){1,2})[\+#]?(\s*[\!\?]+)?)(?:\s*(?<varMoveValue2>(?:[PNBRQK]?[a-h]?[1-8]?x?(?:[a-h][1-8]|[NBRQK])(?:\=[PNBRQK])?|O(-?O){1,2})[\+#]?(\s*[\!\?]+)?))?\s*(?:\((?<varVariation>.*)\)\s*)?(?:\{(?<varComment>[^\}]*?)\}\s*)?)*)\s*\)\s*)*(?:\{(?<comment>[^\}]*?)\}\s*)?)*(?<endMarker>1\-?0|0\-?1|1/2\-?1/2|\*)?\s*)""".r

}
```

And the following PGN :

```
[Event "Live Chess"]
[Site "Chess.com"]
[Date "2014.11.17"]
[White "Rafael1978"]
[Black "AChessGeek"]
[Result "1/2-1/2"]
[WhiteElo "1332"]
[BlackElo "1350"]
[TimeControl "15|10"]
[Termination "Partie nulle par pat"]

1.e4 c6 2.Nf3 d5 3.exd5 cxd5 4.d4 Nf6 5.Bg5 e6 6.Ne5 Be7 7.Bxf6 Bxf6 8.Qh5 Bxe5 9.Qxe5 O-O 10.Bd3 Kh8
11.Qh5 g6 12.Qe5+ Kg8 13.h4 Nc6 14.Qe3 Qf6 15.c3 Ne7 16.h5 Nf5 17.Qd2 b6 18.h6 Nh4 19.Rh2 Bd7 20.Na3 Rae8
21.O-O-O e5 22.g3 Nf3 23.Qc2 Nxh2 24.f4 e4 25.Bb5 Bxb5 26.Nxb5 Nf3 27.Nc7 Rd8 28.Qg2 Rd7 29.Nb5 a6 30.Na3 b5
31.b4 Rc8 32.Kc2 Rdc7 33.Nb1 Nxd4+ 34.Kb2 Ne6 35.Rxd5 Rd8 36.Rxd8+ Qxd8 37.Qxe4 Rd7 38.g4 Re7 39.Qf3 g5 40.f5 Nf4
41.f6 Re2+ 42.Ka3 Re1 43.Nd2 a5 44.Nb3 a4 45.Nd4 Nd5 46.Nxb5 Nxf6 47.Nd4 Nd5 48.Nc6 Qd7 49.Qf2 Rc1 50.Qd4 Rxc3+
51.Kb2 f6 52.Ne7+ Qxe7 53.Qxd5+ Qf7 54.Qa8+ Qf8 55.Qxa4 Rg3 56.b5 Rg2+ 57.Kb1 Qe7 58.Qa8+ Kf7 59.Qxg2 Qe1+ 60.Kc2 Qe5
61.Qb7+ Ke6 62.Qc6+ Qd6 63.Qe4+ Qe5 64.Qxe5+ fxe5 65.b6 Kd7 66.a4 Kc6 67.a5 Kb7 68.Kb3 Ka6 69.Kb4 e4 70.Kc5 e3
71.Kc6 e2 72.b7 e1=Q 73.b8=Q Qc3+ 74.Kd7 Qd4+ 75.Qd6+ Qxd6+ 76.Kxd6 Kxa5 77.Ke6 Kb5 78.Kf6 Kc6 79.Kxg5 Kd7 80.Kf6 Ke8
81.g5 Kf8 82.g6 hxg6 83.Kxg6 Kg8 84.h7+ Kh8 85.Kh6 1/2-1/2
```

But the result is not the one I want to go with :

```
Group id => [Event "Live Chess"]
[Site "Chess.com"]
[Date "2014.11.17"]
[White "Rafael1978"]
[Black "AChessGeek"]
[Result "1/2-1/2"]
[WhiteElo "1332"]
[BlackElo "1350"]
[TimeControl "15|10"]
[Termination "Partie nulle par pat"]

1.e4 c6 2.Nf3 d5 3.exd5 cxd5 4.d4 Nf6 5.Bg5 e6 6.Ne5 Be7 7.Bxf6 Bxf6 8.Qh5 Bxe5 9.Qxe5 O-O 10.Bd3 Kh8
11.Qh5 g6 12.Qe5+ Kg8 13.h4 Nc6 14.Qe3 Qf6 15.c3 Ne7 16.h5 Nf5 17.Qd2 b6 18.h6 Nh4 19.Rh2 Bd7 20.Na3 Rae8
21.O-O-O e5 22.g3 Nf3 23.Qc2 Nxh2 24.f4 e4 25.Bb5 Bxb5 26.Nxb5 Nf3 27.Nc7 Rd8 28.Qg2 Rd7 29.Nb5 a6 30.Na3 b5
31.b4 Rc8 32.Kc2 Rdc7 33.Nb1 Nxd4+ 34.Kb2 Ne6 35.Rxd5 Rd8 36.Rxd8+ Qxd8 37.Qxe4 Rd7 38.g4 Re7 39.Qf3 g5 40.f5 Nf4
41.f6 Re2+ 42.Ka3 Re1 43.Nd2 a5 44.Nb3 a4 45.Nd4 Nd5 46.Nxb5 Nxf6 47.Nd4 Nd5 48.Nc6 Qd7 49.Qf2 Rc1 50.Qd4 Rxc3+
51.Kb2 f6 52.Ne7+ Qxe7 53.Qxd5+ Qf7 54.Qa8+ Qf8 55.Qxa4 Rg3 56.b5 Rg2+ 57.Kb1 Qe7 58.Qa8+ Kf7 59.Qxg2 Qe1+ 60.Kc2 Qe5
61.Qb7+ Ke6 62.Qc6+ Qd6 63.Qe4+ Qe5 64.Qxe5+ fxe5 65.b6 Kd7 66.a4 Kc6 67.a5 Kb7 68.Kb3 Ka6 69.Kb4 e4 70.Kc5 e3
71.Kc6 e2 72.b7 e1=Q 73.b8=Q Qc3+ 74.Kd7 Qd4+ 75.Qd6+ Qxd6+ 76.Kxd6 Kxa5 77.Ke6 Kb5 78.Kf6 Kc6 79.Kxg5 Kd7 80.Kf6 Ke8
81.g5 Kf8 82.g6 hxg6 83.Kxg6 Kg8 84.h7+ Kh8 85.Kh6 1/2-1/2

Group id => [Termination "Partie nulle par pat"]


Group id => Termination
Group id => Partie nulle par pat
Group id => 85.Kh6 
Group id => 85
Group id => .
Group id => Kh6
Group id => -O
Group id => null
Group id => Kh8
Group id => -O
Group id => null
Group id => null
Group id => null
Group id => null
Group id => null
Group id => null
Group id => null
Group id => null
Group id => null
Group id => null
Group id => null
Group id => null
Group id => null
Group id => 1/2-1/2
```

How can I achieve the following result (just for the main line, ignoring all variations that might occurs for now) ?

```
Tag => [Site "Chess.com"]
Tag => [Date "2014.11.17"]
Tag => [White "Rafael1978"]
Tag => [Black "AChessGeek"]
Tag => [Result "1/2-1/2"]
Tag => [WhiteElo "1332"]
Tag => [BlackElo "1350"]
Tag => [TimeControl "15|10"]
Tag => [Termination "Partie nulle par pat"]

Move => e4
Move => c6
...
Move => Kh6
```

Comment: Probably not the answer you want, but regexes are a bad way to parse file formats. There are some [PGN parsing libraries](https://github.com/supareno/pgn-parser) for the JVM already, you could use those; if you must write your own parser I find using scala-parser-combinators much easier to understand and debug.

Comment: Thank you, I agree with this and I am now trying to use scala parser combinators.